# Spinning Cube with program using shaders not working

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

In translating the spinning cube example application from the OpenGL SuperBible 7th Ed. I've run into a snag. I think it has to do with how I'm supplying the vertex data, as the cube is not being displayed at all.

Search for the line "vao = glGenVertexArrays();" to find where I think the relevant part starts.

Following is the program in full. Also here is a link to this program on github [spinning cube](https://github.com/quaternion2/Ch5SpinningCube). And here is a link to the version I am trying to translate from: [OpenGL Supper bible "spinnycube"](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/tree/master/src/spinnycube)

```
package com.openglsb;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.joml.Matrix4f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.glfwFreeCallbacks;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_FALSE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_RELEASE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_TRUE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwDefaultWindowHints;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwDestroyWindow;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetWindowSize;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetKeyCallback;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSetWindowShouldClose;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwShowWindow;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapInterval;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwTerminate;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWindowHint;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_CULL_FACE;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_CW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_FLOAT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_LEQUAL;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_VERSION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDepthFunc;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glFrontFace;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetString;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glAttachShader;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCompileShader;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCreateProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCreateShader;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glDeleteProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glDeleteShader;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetProgrami;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetShaderi;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetUniformLocation;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glLinkProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUseProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glValidateProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glBindVertexArray;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glClearBufferfv;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public class Ch5SpinningCube {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ch5SpinningCube app = new Ch5SpinningCube();
        app.run();
    }

    private long window;
    private int program;
    private int vao;
    private int buffer;
    private int mv_location;
    private int proj_location;
    //private float aspect;
    private final FloatBuffer proj_matrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    static float vertex_positions[]
            = {
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f
            };

    private void init() {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }
        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
            }
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try (MemoryStack stack = stackPush()) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);// Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()); // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            glfwSetWindowPos(// Center the window
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);// Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwSwapInterval(1);        // Enable v-sync

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();//Critical
        System.out.println("OpenGL Verion: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        this.compileShader();

        mv_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix");
        proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix");

        vao = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        buffer = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

        GL15.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                vertex_positions,
                GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        loop();

        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void loop() {

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            final float green[] = {0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
            final float one[] = {1.0f};

            IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
            IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, w, h);
            int width = w.get(0);
            int height = h.get(0);
            float aspect = (float) width / (float) height;
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            new Matrix4f()
                    .perspective((float) Math.toRadians(50.0f), aspect, 0.01f, 1000.0f)
                    .lookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f,
                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).set(this.proj_matrix);

            double curTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0;
            float t = (float) curTime * 0.3f;//assigned direcly but I was applying a factor here

            glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
            glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one);

            glUseProgram(program);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, false, proj_matrix);

            FloatBuffer mv_matrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
            new Matrix4f().translate(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f))
                    .translate(
                            new Vector3f(
                                    (float) Math.sin(2.1 * t) * 0.5f,
                                    (float) Math.cos(1.7 * t) * 0.5f,
                                    (float) Math.sin(1.3 * t)
                                    * (float) Math.cos(1.5 * t) * 2.0f)
                    )
                    .rotate((float) Math.toRadians(45.0f) * t, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
                    .rotate((float) Math.toRadians(81.0f) * t, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
                    .set(mv_matrix);

            glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, false, mv_matrix);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
        glDeleteProgram(program);
    }

    private String readFileAsString(String filename) {
        String next = new Scanner(Ch5SpinningCube.class.getResourceAsStream(filename), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println("readFileAsString: " + next);
        return next;
    }

    private void compileShader() {
        int vertex_shader = createShader("/vert.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        checkShader(vertex_shader);
        int fragment_shader = createShader("/frag.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        checkShader(fragment_shader);
        program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        //check link       
        if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_LINK_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        glValidateProgram(program);
        if (glGetProgrami(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        //delete shaders as the program has them now
        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    }

    public int createShader(final String path, final int shaderType) {
        String shaderSource = readFileAsString(path);
        int shader_id = glCreateShader(shaderType);
        glShaderSource(shader_id, shaderSource);
        glCompileShader(shader_id);
        return shader_id;
    }

    public void checkShader(final int shaderId) {
        if (glGetShaderi(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId));
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

For reference here is the vertex shader (vert.glsl):

```
    #version 410 core                                                 

    in vec4 position;

    out VS_OUT {

        vec4 color;
    } vs_out;

    uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
    uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

    void main(void) 
    {
        gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;
        vs_out.color = position * 2.0 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    }
```

and the fragment shader (frag.glsl):

```
#version 410 core                                                

out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT {
    vec4 color;
} fs_in;

void main(void) {
    color = fs_in.color;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with your code, this is kind of strange ```glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);``` try to replace it by always and finally i am not sure if you get any alpha in the shaders, try returning a solid color first ```color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);```

Comment: You are using the clock-wise culling, but your vertices are defined as counter clock wise. Try changing it to `glFrontFace(GL_CCW); `. Furthermore, check for any error uing `glGetError()` to know whether theres something failing which you are missing.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so if you have successfully built the projects from the github handle of superbible 7th edition, and running the spinnycube_d.exe gives you a blank green screen, then try resizing the window, you will be able to to see the spinning cube now. The reason for this is that the first assignment of the proj_matrix (projection matrix) lies in the onResize() function, and this function is called only if we have resized the window at least once during run time, but until then the proj_matrix is uninitiated, hence it consists of zeros (as garbage values).
Now if you want to resolve this issue, we need to initialize this proj_matrix in the startup() function, so place this statement in the startup() function:
Proj_matrix = vmath::perspective(50.0f, (float) (800/600), 0.1f, 1000.0f) ;
And now rebuild the project, and run the sinnycube_d.exe file, you can see the cube now (without any resizing).